# Microsoft Application Insights on Cordova requests goes to file://

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, azure-application-insights

I am trying to use Application Insight for Cordova (ionic) based app and facing following issue.

App insight JS requesting to **file://** dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track instead **https://**

I understand this is because app is hosted in android device using **file://**

I also tried using cordova plug in provided by MS, appInsight object becoming null.

below is the code i am using

```html
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
    function r(config){t[config]=function(){var i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},u=document,e=window,o="script",s=u.createElement(o),i,f;for(s.src=config.url||"http://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s),t.cookie=u.cookie,t.queue=[],i=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace"];i.length;)r("track"+i.pop());return r("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),r("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),config.disableExceptionTracking||(i="onerror",r("_"+i),f=e[i],e[i]=function(config,r,u,e,o){var s=f&&f(config,r,u,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+i](config,r,u,e,o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey: "--key--"
      
    });

    window.appInsights=appInsights;
```

please note, in the above code i have added **http://** to download ai.0.js file. Otherwise that request also goes to *file://*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @John for creating issue on git. I found a way to use it for cordova apps as like below

I added following option along with instrumentationKey

```
endpointUrl: "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track"
```

It worked. I am not sure if this is right way, but it works. Actually i dont want to copy ai.0.js to my project because I am not sure what to do if Microsoft changes the ai.0.js, Then it will be hard to push changes to all installed devices.

Comment: yup, i also figured that out today when i was adding more info to the github bug.  as a user you have to manually specify the protocol in both places, in the config and in the initial snippet that loads the sdk, otherwise both places try to use the file:// protocol.

Comment: and yes, until it gets fixed in the recommended snippet and in the ai.0.js, this is the correct way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a question of setting endpoint: after the instrumentation key. But I'm unsure if there's much experience of using App Insights with Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

The sample snippet that you are using written that way so that if your site is `https`, the ai script is also retrieved via `https`, so you don't get failures and errors about unsecure content.   It uses the same protocol that the rest of the site used for consistency.

If you're doing this locally in a cordova, you'll have to customize the injection code like you have, because that snippet is intended for use in a browser, not in a file based app. you might also want to copy the ai.0.js file locally into your project, and modify the script to use that local copy of the file, so that your app doesn't have to download it every time?

**Edit:** i've also opened [issue #93](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/93) at the App Insights JS github project to track this